# jQuery parseXML, one tag at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I am trying to parse my xml using jquery to make a table. I have this code bellow, I know right now it isn't a loop. However it returns all the tags "id" together. How would I be able to access one at a time, so i can place the data in a table.

```
$.get("xml.xml", function(data, status){
      xmlDoc = $.parseXML( data ),
      $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
      alert($xml.find( "id" ).text());
```

Here is an example of my xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:films xmlns:ns2="xml.jaxb.model">
    <filmList>
        <films>
            <id>10377</id>
            <name>FIST OF THE NORTH STAR</name>
            <year>1996</year>
            <director>TONY RANDEL</director>
            <stars>GARY DANIELS, COSTAS MANDYLOR</stars>
            <review>Live-action adaptation of the famous Japanese Manga. British martial artist Daniels stars as Kenshiro, the title character, wandering the barren post-atomic world battling an evil tyrant who has kidnapped Kenshiros bride to be. His enemy is his own brother, the Fist Of The Southern Cross, and a titanic battle is looming. Atmospheric and action-packed. Chris Penn, Malcolm McDowell and Melvin Van Peebles lend support.</review>
        </films>
        <films>
            <id>10742</id>
            <name>ONE TOUGH BASTARD</name>
            <year>1995</year>
            <director>KURT WIMMER</director>
            <stars>BRIAN BOSWORTH, BRUCE PAYNE</stars>
            <review>Somewhat indelicate title but definitely appropriate, considering the character played here by Brian Bosworth (Stone Cold). Hes an ex-drill sergeant who survives an attack that kills his wife and daughter and goes on the predictable revenge trail, only  to discover that the killer is on the US Witness Protection Program and is being shielded by the police. Thus he has to take on both sides of the law. Punchy.</review>
        </films>
    </filmList>
</ns2:films>
```

**EDIT**
I have tried the .each with the ParseXML but this isnt working. Tried researching for about an hour and i cant see what im doing wrong here. Nothing is being outputted on the alert.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.get("http://localhost:8080/rest/films/name/queen/xml", function(data, status){
      alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
      xmlDoc = $.parseXML( data ),
      $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
      $xml.find( "films" ).each(function() {
          alert($(this).find("id").text());
      }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: `$xml.find("is").each(function() { ... })`

Comment: Ive tried this, However it wont work. Uploaded my code any help would be great.

Comment: What exactly does "wont work" mean? Does *anything* happen? Are errors reported? How sure are you that the XML is being parsed the way you think it is?

Comment: No errors are being made, the alert just wont come up. I am sure the xml is being parsed, as I tried just finding films and it outputted it as it should be.